# PHP create file on server to download

Tags: php

I try to create a file on a Webserver and than download it. Using this code

```
<?php
$text = "test";
$filename = 'Testfile.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX) or die ("Unable to open file!");

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($filename);
?>
```

The problem is, I always get the "unable to open file!".. if I try it without the or die..... it downloads the file but is is empty. I tried to crate an folder on the server with all rights (chmod 777...) but and than load/create the file there but that also don't work. :(

Comment: Why write to disk. Just use the string

Comment: It seems that your permissions are not set properly. Is the folder you created the same as the one with the PHP script in it? Check permissions for the folder you're writing to again and make sure you write to the same folder you have proper rights for.

Comment: Ok, it must be something with the permissions.. If I create the file "/tmp/Testfile.txt" it works! but then my File is called _tmp_Testfile.txt is there a way to handle that ? I tried to let the name "Testfile.txt" and change the path where I write --> file_put_contents("/tmp/$filename", $text,... but that also result in the Filename _tmp_Testfile.txt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "test";
$filename = 'Testfile.txt';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    file_put_contents($filename, $text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX) or die ("Unable to open file!");
} else {
    echo "You Do not have write permission to this FILE.";
}
```

Comment: hmmm that is confusing to me, the "You Do not have write permission to this FILE." is now written into the file ^^

Comment: Means, If there is THIS `Testfile.txt`, You are not allowed to write content into it..

Answer (score 0):

Use `filewrite` and also check the folder has write permission

```
$text = '123';
$filename = "Testfile.txt";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $text);
fclose($fh);


header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: No, it does not download anything, it only download an empty file if I execute without the or die...

Comment: please check your folder have write permission.

Comment: I also comment that to the answer above ;) ### Ok, it must be something with the permissions.. If I create the file "/tmp/Testfile.txt" it works! but then my File is called _tmp_Testfile.txt is there a way to handle that ? I tried to let the name "Testfile.txt" and change the path where I write --> file_put_contents("/tmp/$filename", $text,... but that also result in the Filename _tmp_Testfile.txt.